# Is getString("K") able to extract int value from json Object?

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to understand why getString is used to parse integer value from JSON Object

i looked in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#getString(java.lang.String))
and it says:

> getString
>
> public String getString (String name)
>
> Returns the value mapped by name if it exists, coercing it if necessary, or throws if no such mapping exists.

The json file is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json)

***please note*** that **"id"**: has integer value

and here is the code in MainActivity

```java
// looping through all Contacts
for (int i = 0; i < pokemons.length(); i++) {
    //TODO: get the JSONObject and its three attributes
    JSONObject c = pokemons.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = c.getString("name");
    >>>  String id = c.getString("id");    <<<
    String candy = c.getString("candy");

    // tmp hash map for a single pokemon
    HashMap<String, String> pokemon = new HashMap<>();

    // add each child node to HashMap key => value
    pokemon.put("name", name);
    pokemon.put("id", id);
    pokemon.put("candy", candy);

    // adding a pokemon to our pokemon list
    pokemonList.add(pokemon);
}
```

Shouldn't it be *getInt()* instead of *getString()*? because as you see in the json file **id: is a key to an int value**!
i tried parsing it with *getInt()* and assign it to an int variable and it worked too!!

**NOTE** that code is from a tuturial on http networking and it is working as intended without crash or error  and it is not my code.

Comment: it should be `getInt()` and what do you mean by `getString()` is used. This looks to be your code. Why don't you change it?

Comment: I would say it doesn't necessary have to be Integer. I think these IDs are usually opaque and the type can be string for example if you want to accommodate easily for changes of the type. Imagine that tomorrow you migrate the database and IDs become uuids and instead of simple integers, they're now strings. But I agree that since this is your code, you can change it.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 @Fred i have added a note: its not my code , its a tutorial code, and the app is working that way with `String id = c.getString("id");`

Answer (score 1):

It should be `getInt(String name)` and you should change it. Or you can use `optInt(String name, int fallback)` also. Documentation is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optInt(java.lang.String,%20int))

Also, if you change it then you will have to change

```
pokemon.put("id", id);
```

to either

`pokemon.put("id", id + "");` or `pokemon.put("id", String.valueOf(id));`

because your HashMap expects a string in the value field.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
int id = c.getInt("id");
```

> JsonObject has method with name 
>    getInt()

Comment: Do you really expect to put `int` to `string` just by assignment? I am more worried about who upvoted to this.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 My bad , i missed changing it while copying it, Thanks for pointing. It would be better if you would have suggested an edit